# I am non-EU citizenI have a family residence in Italy . Can I travel to UK without a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, british-airways

I am an Egyptian man married to an Italian woman. We live in Italy. I have a residence card for a family member of a union citizen issued from Italy. Is it possible to travel with my wife to uk without a visa?![image]

Comment: You can use this card to travel to the UK without a visa before the end of 2020 but only if your wife comes with you or is already there when you arrive.

Comment: I asked the airline that I wanted to travel through. They told me that I could travel, but not from Italy, but from another country, like France. For example, I asked another airline that I could not travel without a visa even if my wife was traveling with me, I'm confused now, I don't know what the truth is.

Comment: The airline was confused.  You can use that document in lieu of a visa to travel to any EU country with your wife (or to join her), and you can use it to travel to any Schengen country even without your wife.  The point of departure is irrelevant.  Tell the airline to check TIMATIC.  Also see this link from my answer to the duplicate question: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card

Comment: I checked TIMATIC ITA and gave me this warning Union Citizens are nationals of an EEA Member State and Switzerland who moved from the country of nationality to reside in another EEA Member State or in Switzerland.
 The visa exemption for family members of a Union Citizen applies if the residence permit is issued by:
 -- the country of residence, which must be different from the country of nationality of the Union Citizen, or
 -- the country of nationality of the Union Citizen, if the Union Citizen and family member returned within 6 months after departing from the country of residence.

Comment: I am married to an Italian citizen and my residence permit issued by Italy. Will this be a reason to prevent my travel with my wife to the United Kingdom with my residence permit?